# Connection timeout error on one database, but not on copy of database on same server

Tags: .net, timeout, dataadapter

I have a .net 4.7 web application that reads data from a SQL Server database located on the same server.  I run into the following .net error when trying to read a certain set of records from the database:
The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

This isn't a connection error, because I can read a different set of records from the same page in my web application.  If I point my web application to a copy of the same database and attempt to read the records that were causing the error, the page generates without error and returns the records without error, so I believe I can eliminate the data as the cause of the error.

So, if I'm not having a connection error to the SQL server or the database, and I'm not having a data error....what other things could be causing the timeout error?

Specifically, the error is happening in the code when I fill a dataset using the .net DataAdapter.fill procedure, and at the SQL client.tdsparser.try run procedure.  At this point in the code, it throws an exception error.

EDIT: I found the answer to my error...see my comment below.

Comment: could you paste a code that you write to read data from db?

Comment: How many records are you trying to read?

Comment: I found the cause of my error. There is a table in the database that has a column with a varchar(10) datatype.  However, in the stored procedures that my code was calling, it was trying to create a temporary table for that column as varchar(6).  When I updated the datatype in the stored procedure to varchar(10) to match the actual datatype of the actual column, the timeout issues went away.  I was only trying to read about 30 records from the database, so it shouldn't have been timing out.  I would think it would send a different error for mismatched datatypes....